# Making div as model on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My problem is I need to open div on click with all its data in popup/modal fading the background.

HTML :

```
<div ng-app = "angulo" ng-controller="testController">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 checkContent" ng-repeat = "appreciate in CustAppre">
                    <div class="quote-inner-wrapper">   
                        <div class="arrow_box blue-texture-bg" ng-click="openBigDiv(appreciate)">
                            <blockquote class="no-bg white quotation-white">
                                <p>{{appreciate.title}}</p>
                                <div ng-show="appreciate.opened">{{appreciate.content}}</div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <a role="button" class="customerName blue" href="#">{{appreciate.by}}</a>        
                    </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('angulo', []);
app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $log) {

$scope.CustAppre = [        
{title:"Project Appreciation",by:"Ziva Roe",content:"1 popup good job"},
{title:"Agile Work Process",by:"Joe Roe",content:"2 pop up very good job"},
{title:"Customer Speaks",by:"Michael Charles",content:"3 popup a very good job"},
];

$scope.openBigDiv = function(title) {
title.opened = !title.opened;
    };
```

});

Here is my fiddle. Please advise.

https://jsfiddle.net/f98engoa/11/

Comment: what do you mean by open  div?

Comment: For time being I hav given my div a class = "popup" and managed it with css .popup{padding:10px;display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:30px;width:200px;background:black;} . Please suggest if I am heading correct or should move for some better solution.

Comment: I mean on click, the div should maximise up as popup....just as on button click a popup form comes up in most of the sites

Comment: can't you use angular bootstrap modal?

Comment: I tried using but it works independently and when it comes to integrate with my code.....it some how does not work. Most of them showcase their model in directive template which I do not want to...

Comment: will check again if I am missing something using bootstrap modal....if I crack it...will update the same

Comment: Have updated my HTML code using bootstrap angular model....now elements of ng-repeat not working .....I m new to angularjs please help....https://jsfiddle.net/f98engoa/11/ updated fiddle